# What could increase the consumed server memory amount when just upgrade the RAM?

Tags: windows-server-2008, configuration, memory

Is there any reason that could cause more memory consumption on a windows server 2008 when upgrade the RAM from 2 to 3 or 4 GB?

I have noticed that the server used memory was about 1.5 to 1.8 GB when RAM was 2GB while it changed to 1.8 to 2.1GB after upgrading the total RAM to 3GB while we didn't change anything in installed software, running services and no changes in server usage, domains and visits.

Comment: Wouldn't you be upset if you added more RAM to improve server performance and instead the server just left that RAM empty, wasting it?

Comment: without background, I didn't think that way first but now after I knew and watched, sure there is difference now and server, services and shutdown frequently are being better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Windows will use all available memory not in use by an application for various caches, the largest one being the disk cache. If your server has even a moderate amount of disk activity and a small amount of RAM (and 4 GB is small-ish) then it's not surprising that all of your RAM is being used.

So the fact that your total memory utilization went up when you added more RAM means that Windows was able to effectively cache more disk in memory. This is a good thing.

Comment: The same thing happens on Linux—[linuxatemyram.com](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/) applies here too :).